# Passing elements of array to an Oracle database table using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets, oracle10g

Good morning everyone !
I have created a jsp page having some radio buttons. Now I am receiving the user response for those radio buttons in an array inside a servlet. Now I want to send these array items to my oracle database table .
      But I am getting problems.
Code for the jsp page is :

```
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="TestAms" method="post">
<%
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int md = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);
    for(int i = 0; i <= md; i++){
        %>
            <input type="radio" name="<%= i%>" value="<%=i %>">
        <%
    }
%>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code for the servlet is :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestAms extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int md = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);
    int count =0;
    String s[] = new String[md+1];

    String jan = "JAN";
    String query;

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","urja","urja");

        for (int y=1; y<=md; y++){
            s[y] = request.getParameter(Integer.toString(y));
            out.println(s[y]);
            if( y  < md ){
                int z = y+1;
                out.println("db var : " + z);
                query = "UPDATE V_TEST SET \"" + z + "\" = ? WHERE V_MONTH = '"+ jan +"'";
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                pstmt.setString(z, s[y]);                   //getting error in this line as per the debug report.
                int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                out.println("inserted : " + i);
            }
        }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
                pstmt.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

My Table sql is :

```
CREATE TABLE  "V_TEST" 
(   "V_MONTH" VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"1" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"2" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"3" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"4" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"5" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"6" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"7" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"8" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"9" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"10" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"11" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"12" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"13" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"14" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"15" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"16" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"17" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"18" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"19" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"20" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"21" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"22" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"23" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"24" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"25" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"26" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"27" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"28" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"29" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"30" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"31" VARCHAR2(4000)
);
```

The complete error that I am getting is :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.checkBindsInAndOut(OracleStatement.java:1876)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2638)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:589)
at TestAms.doPost(TestAms.java:47)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[image: My Database looks like this]

I want to store the date (date for which the radio buttons in the jsp page has been checked) in each column.

This is my jsp page.
[image: jsp page]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kinds of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be brutally honest, there's quite a lot that you're doing wrong here.

Firstly, *use parameterised SQL*.  Use PreparedStatements.  *Don't build up your SQL string using concatenation unless you absolutely have to*, as otherwise you will find yourself the victim of a SQL injection attack.   As is obligatory when discussing SQL injection these days, here is the link to the xkcd comic on SQL injection: http://www.xkcd.com/327.

Secondly, you are getting the ORA-00927 error because the SQL statement you are sending to the database is invalid.  I'm not aware that square brackets are valid anywhere in Oracle SQL (outside of strings and double-quoted identifiers).  `s[md]` may have a value as a Java expression, but inside a string it doesn't get evaluated, and so the database is asked to execute a query `UPDATE V_TEST SET s[md]= ...`, which it doesn't understand.

Oracle knows that a SQL statement should be of the form

```
UPDATE table SET column = value ....
```

With your query it got as far as `UPDATE V_TEST SET s`, thought `s` was the name of the column and then it got surprised because it found a `[` when it wanted a `=`.

Also, your column names are numbers, so they will need to be surrounded in double-quotes as otherwise Oracle will think you are trying to assign a value to a number.  `UPDATE V_TEST SET 1 = 'xyz'` is not valid SQL, `UPDATE V_TEST SET "1" = 'xyz'` is.

Instead of writing,

```
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    //Query is not right
    int i = stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE V_TEST SET s[md] = '"+s[md]+"' WHERE V_MONTH = '"+jan+"'");
```

write

```
    // Use \" to escape the double-quotes, so that the query ends up like
    // UPDATE V_TEST SET "30" = ? WHERE V_MONTH = ?
    // In this case we have to use string concatenation to build up the query,
    // but we're only inserting an integer so this won't be a problem.
    String sql = "UPDATE V_TEST SET \"" + md + "\" = ? WHERE V_MONTH = ?";

    // stmt will need to be declared as a PreparedStatement, not a Statement.
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    // Set the values for the two '?' placeholders.
    stmt.setString(1, s[md]);
    stmt.setString(2, jan);

    int i = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

This should fix the first two of your problems.

Thirdly, it seems you are running out of connections because you are not closing your connections (except if your queries succeed, which they aren't doing at the moment).  You should be closing them in `finally` blocks, as that makes sure that they are closed even in the event of an exception being thrown.

You should be doing something like the following (this is a sketch):

```
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        // get database connection ...

        // do stuff with connection ...
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        // handle error connecting to the database or using it
    } 
    finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                // handle error disconnecting from the database.
            }
        }
    }
```

As well as closing connections, it's also good practice to close `Statement`s and `PreparedStatement`s once you've finished with them.

Fourthly, you are creating a new database connection (which will create a new process on the server) each time you go through your loop.  This is completely unnecessary.  You should create the database connection once before the loop, use the same connection throughout the loop, and only close the connection at the end of the loop.  Because you're creating so many connections in a loop, and not closing any of them, you end up hitting the limit of database processes very quickly.

Fifthly, I strongly recommend using the Oracle JDBC driver (class name `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`, in a JAR named `ojdbc6.jar` or similar), not the 'old' JDBC-ODBC bridge driver, which [will be removed from Java in Java 8](https://blogs.oracle.com/Lance/entry/removal_of_the_jdbc_odbc).

Sixthly, even if your SQL is fixed as I suggested, it is unlikely to do what you want.  At present it will only set a value for the column corresponding to the last day of the current month.  Did you perhaps mean to update the column with the name `y` instead?

**EDIT** in response to your edited question:  the problem is with this line:

```
            pstmt.setString(z, s[y]);                   //getting error in this line as per the debug report.
```

This should be

```
            pstmt.setString(1, s[y]);
```

The number `1` is the index of the placeholder `?` in the query.  These indexes start at 1.  You only have one placeholder in your query, so it has index 1.

Comment: In my application user is clicking on radio buttons. Each radio button represent one day of the month. It is a part of my attendance project. All radio buttons have name= date of that month.So all checked radio buttons returns the date of the month while the unchecked radio buttons returns "null". In the servlet I am capturing those responses and storing it to the database. Since I need to make the attendance daily so I need to run that loop daily to update the attendance. Your previous answers are not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Here the bounty goes to you. :)